# calculate combinations based on column?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am looking for a efficient way in R to derive possible combinations. I have a data frame with 10 columns and on the basis of the 1 and 2 column i would like to calculate all combinations of reported values (eg when whit_spouse and whit_alone at 4:00 equals Reported ).

```
structure(list(id = 1:6, time = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = c("04:00", "04:10", "04:20", "04:30", "04:40", 
"04:50", "05:00", "05:10", "05:20", "05:30", "05:40", "05:50", 
"06:00", "06:10", "06:20", "06:30", "06:40", "06:50", "07:00", 
"07:10", "07:20", "07:30", "07:40", "07:50", "08:00", "08:10", 
"08:20", "08:30", "08:40", "08:50", "09:00", "09:10", "09:20", 
"09:30", "09:40", "09:50", "10:00", "10:10", "10:20", "10:30", 
"10:40", "10:50", "11:00", "11:10", "11:20", "11:30", "11:40", 
"11:50", "12:00", "12:10", "12:20", "12:30", "12:40", "12:50", 
"13:00", "13:10", "13:20", "13:30", "13:40", "13:50", "14:00", 
"14:10", "14:20", "14:30", "14:40", "14:50", "15:00", "15:10", 
"15:20", "15:30", "15:40", "15:50", "16:00", "16:10", "16:20", 
"16:30", "16:40", "16:50", "17:00", "17:10", "17:20", "17:30", 
"17:40", "17:50", "18:00", "18:10", "18:20", "18:30", "18:40", 
"18:50", "19:00", "19:10", "19:20", "19:30", "19:40", "19:50", 
"20:00", "20:10", "20:20", "20:30", "20:40", "20:50", "21:00", 
"21:10", "21:20", "21:30", "21:40", "21:50", "22:00", "22:10", 
"22:20", "22:30", "22:40", "22:50", "23:00", "23:10", "23:20", 
"23:30", "23:40", "23:50", "00:00", "00:10", "00:20", "00:30", 
"00:40", "00:50", "01:00", "01:10", "01:20", "01:30", "01:40", 
"01:50", "02:00", "02:10", "02:20", "02:30", "02:40", "02:50", 
"03:00", "03:10", "03:20", "03:30", "03:40", "03:50"), class = "factor"), 
    whereat = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("At home", 
    "Not At home"), class = "factor"), whit_spouse = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Not reported", "Reported"
    ), class = "factor"), whit_alone = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Not reported", "Reported"), class = "factor"), 
    whit_mother = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Not reported", 
    "Reported"), class = "factor"), whit_father = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Not reported", "Reported"
    ), class = "factor"), whit_otherpeople = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Not reported", "Reported"
    ), class = "factor"), whit_otherpeopleoutsidehh = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Not reported", "Reported"
    ), class = "factor"), whit_child_con = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Not reported", "Reported"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")


Example of input: 

id time whereat whit_spouse whit_alone       whit_mother     whit_father 
1 04:00 At home Reported    Not reported     Reported        Reported...    
2 04:00 At home Reported    Not reported     Not reported    Not reported ....
```

Example of output:

```
id time whereat Together (Reported)       Frequency
1 04:00 At home whit_mother, wit_father   1
2 04:00 At home -                         0
```

At the end I would like to identify the most frequent combination:

eg. Together

Comment: you meant by 'id', 'time'?

Comment: @akrun yes based on id and time the reported values , so for example a reported value could be  4:00 whit_alone, with_mother

Comment: Do you mean--you want to keep the current combinations of `id` and `time`, not adding any missing time/id combinations, but within each id/time combination you want to add rows so that every combination of the other 8 columns is present? Or something else? It would help a lot if you could show your expected output for your nice sample input. For illustrative purposes, it might also help to reduce the number of columns to 2 or 3 columns apart from the `time` and `id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `tidyverse` to do that. Here is the code to calculate the number of occurrences of all the combinations by "time", "whit_spouse" and "whit_alone". If you want to summarize other type of variables, you could use `summarize`.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  group_by(time, whit_alone, whit_spouse) %>%
  count()
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .N, .(time, whit_alone, whit_spouse)]
```